# Lógica para consulta em sistema de assinaturas

Tags: mysql

Olá,
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de assinaturas de planos online para um cliente, e me deparei com diversas dificuldades. Vou explicar um pouco do funcionamento do sistema e quais as dificuldades que estou tendo.

- Meu sistema possui 8 planos, cadastrados em uma tabela chamada Planos.
- Cada assinatura pode ter mais de um plano,.
- Uma assinatura pode conter mais de um usuário.

Até aí, OK. Porém, estou tendo dificuldades na ordenação de alguns itens. Preciso listar todos os registros dos Usuários cadastrados. Porém, devem listar apenas os que estão com a assinatura regular. Esta é a primeira dificuldade.

O que define a situação regular é um registro em uma tabela chamada AssinaturaPlano, que guarda o ID da assinatura e do plano, e contem uma flag chamada Situação, que se for igual a 3, está tudo OK. Porém, nesta tabela, não consta o ID do usuário, já que o mesmo fica em outra tabela, chamada AssinaturaUsuario. Não estou sabendo como capturar esta informação na mesma consulta que já estou fazendo:

**Esta consulta traz os usuários ativos da cidade Curitiba:**

`SELECT * FROM sistema_cliente c INNER JOIN sistema_assinatura_cliente ac ON ac.cliId = c.cliId WHERE cliAtivo = 'S' AND cliExcluido = 'N' AND cidId IN (SELECT cidId FROM sistema_assinatura_cidade WHERE cidId IN (2878)) LIMIT 0,15`

Como posso fazer para trazer apenas os usuários que estão em assinaturas que possuem planos que estão com pagamentos regulares? Não sei se fui claro, rs.

Seguem as tabelas e um exemplo de cadastro para ilustrar:

> **CLIENTES**
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'sistema_cliente' (   'cliId' int(11) NOT
>   NULL,   'cliNome' varchar(255) NOT NULL,   'cliAtivo' enum('S','N')
>   NOT NULL,   'cliExcluido' enum('S','N') NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> INSERT INTO 'sistema_cliente' ('cliId', 'cliNome', 'cliAtivo',
>   'cliExcluido') VALUES (1, 'Maykel Esser', 'S', 'N');
>
> **PLANOS**
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'sistema_planos' (   'plaId' int(11) NOT
>   NULL,   'plaTitulo' varchar(255) NOT NULL,   'plaModalidade'
>   enum('M','T','S','A') NOT NULL,   'plaValor' float NOT NULL,
>   'plaDataCadastro' datetime NOT NULL,   'plaAtivo' enum('S','N') NOT
>   NULL,   'plaExcluido' enum('S','N') NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> INSERT INTO 'sistema_planos' ('plaId', 'plaTitulo', 'plaModalidade',
>   'plaValor', 'plaDataCadastro', 'plaAtivo', 'plaExcluido') VALUES (1,
>   'Tradicional', 'M', 19.9, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (2,
>   'Tradicional', 'T', 49.9, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (3,
>   'Tradicional', 'S', 89.9, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (4,
>   'Tradicional', 'A', 129.9, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (5,
>   'Escritório', 'M', 59.9, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (6,
>   'Escritório', 'T', 149.9, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (7,
>   'Escritório', 'S', 269.9, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (8,
>   'Escritório', 'A', 389.9, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (9,
>   'Benefícios - Bronze', 'M', 3, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (10,
>   'Benefícios - Prata', 'M', 7, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N'), (11,
>   'Benefícios - Ouro', 'M', 14, '2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'S', 'N');
>
> **ASSINATURAS**
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'sistema_assinatura' (   'assId' int(11)
>   NOT NULL,   'assDataCadastro' datetime NOT NULL,   'assAtivo'
>   enum('S','N') NOT NULL,   'assExcluido' enum('S','N') NOT NULL )
>   ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> INSERT INTO 'sistema_assinatura' ('assId', 'assDataCadastro',
>   'assAtivo', 'assExcluido') VALUES (1, '2017-04-14 22:42:33', 'S',
>   'N');
>
> **ASSINATURA-CLIENTE**
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'sistema_assinatura_cliente' (   'ascId'
>   int(11) NOT NULL,   'assId' int(11) NOT NULL,   'cliId' int(11) NOT
>   NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> INSERT INTO 'sistema_assinatura_cliente' ('ascId', 'assId', 'cliId')
>   VALUES (1, 1, 1);
>
> **ASSINATURA-PLANO**
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'sistema_assinatura_plano' (   'aspId'
>   int(11) NOT NULL,   'aspSituacao' int(1) NOT NULL,
>   'aspDataVencimento' int(2) NOT NULL,   'assId' int(11) NOT NULL,
>   'plaId' int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=utf8;
>
> INSERT INTO 'sistema_assinatura_plano' ('aspId', 'aspSituacao',
>   'aspDataVencimento', 'assId', 'plaId') VALUES (1, 1, 0, 1, 1), (2, 1,
>   0, 1, 9);

Answer (score 0):

Query desejada:

> "Usuários que estão em assinaturas que possuem planos que estão com
>   pagamentos regulares."

**Primeiro passo:**

Precisamos identificar o que quer dizer  "planos que estão com pagamentos regulares".
No meu entender "planos que estão com pagamentos regulares" são os que tem `assAtivo='S'` da tabela `sistema_assinatura` e `aspSituacao = 1` da tabela `sistema_assinatura_plano`.

**Segundo passo:**

Procurar entender todos os dados que devemos pegar para a query.

A) O nome dos usuários vem da tabela `sistema_cliente`, coluna `cliNome`.

B) O nome dos planos e valores vem da tabela `sistema_planos`, colunas `plaTitulo` e `plaValor`.

C) A tabela `sistema_assinatura` guarda a situação da assinatura (`assAtivo`) e o campo `assId` é utilizado para linkar `sistema_assinatura_cliente` e  `sistema_assinatura_plano`.

D) A tabela `sistema_assinatura_cliente` associa uma assinatura a um cliente.

E) A tabela `sistema_assinatura_plano` associa uma assinatura ao plano escolhido.

Baseado nesse entendimento de A,B,C,D e E, podemos montar a query desejada, usando no select os campos que queremos exibir e fazendo todas as linkagens de tabelas no where.

```
SELECT 
    cliNome, plaTitulo, plaValor
FROM 
    sistema_cliente, 
    sistema_planos, 
    sistema_assinatura, 
    sistema_assinatura_cliente, 
    sistema_assinatura_plano
WHERE
    assAtivo='S'
AND
    aspSituacao = 1
AND
    sistema_assinatura_cliente.assId = sistema_assinatura.assId
AND
    sistema_assinatura_cliente.cliId = sistema_cliente.cliId    
AND
    sistema_assinatura_plano.assId = sistema_assinatura.assId
AND
    sistema_assinatura_plano.plaId = sistema_planos.plaId
```

---

**Resposta do comentário**

Usar os inner join com palavra explícita ou de maneira mais *oldschool* linkando as tabelas incluindo os nomes no FROM e as associações no WHERE dá no mesmo. No entando há um certo senso comum que diz que quanto menos sub-queries, melhor. Não sei até que ponto isso é verdade pois não é sempre que uma sub-query vai deixar a query mais lenta, depende muito do otimizador interno do banco.

Rode essa query abaixo e veja se sai o mesmo resultado da que vc colou no comentário. Mudei os joins para essa forma *oldschool* que uso mais e retirei as subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.cliId,
    c.cliNome,
    c.cliAtivo,
    c.cliExcluido
FROM 
    sistema_cliente c, 
    sistema_assinatura_cliente ac,  
    sistema_assinatura a, 
    sistema_assinatura_plano ap,
    sistema_assinatura_cidade
WHERE 
    ac.cliId = c.cliId 
AND
    cliAtivo = 'S' 
AND 
    cliExcluido = 'N' 
AND 
    cidId=2878
AND 
    ap.aspSituacao = 3
AND
    ac.assId = a.assID 
AND
    ap.assId = a.assID 
LIMIT 0,15
```

Comment: na verdade o que define um plano regular é se ele consta como aspSituacao = 3, dentro de sistema_assinatura_plano! Consegui fazer da seguinte maneira usando um WHERE cliId IN (consulta interna), mas não sei se é a maneira mais correta.

Comment: SELECT * FROM sistema_cliente c INNER JOIN sistema_assinatura_cliente ac ON ac.cliId = c.cliId WHERE cliAtivo = 'S' AND cliExcluido = 'N' AND cidId IN (SELECT cidId FROM sistema_assinatura_cidade WHERE cidId IN (2878)) AND c.cliId IN (SELECT cliId FROM sistema_assinatura a INNER JOIN sistema_assinatura_cliente ac ON ac.assId = a.assID INNER JOIN sistema_assinatura_plano ap ON ap.assId = a.assID WHERE ap.aspSituacao = 3) LIMIT 0,15

Comment: Respondi seu comentário acima, editando a minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sistema_cliente c INNER JOIN sistema_assinatura_cliente ac ON ac.cliId = c.cliId WHERE cliAtivo = 'S' AND cliExcluido = 'N' AND cidId IN (SELECT cidId FROM sistema_assinatura_cidade WHERE cidId IN (2878)) AND c.cliId IN (SELECT cliId FROM sistema_assinatura a INNER JOIN sistema_assinatura_cliente ac ON ac.assId = a.assID INNER JOIN sistema_assinatura_plano ap ON ap.assId = a.assID WHERE ap.aspSituacao = 3) LIMIT 0,15
```